# Как запускать скрипты периодически?

Tags: windows

Предположим, есть пакетный файл do.cmd. И нужно этот файл запускать периодически, например, ежедневно в полночь. Как это сделать?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Используйте команду [`at`](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/313565)

Answer (score 1):

Панель управления - Назначенные задания - Добавить задание.